# Why I can't get the user input when &0 stream is redirected

Tags: cmd, batch-file

Examples:

```
set /p= 0>nul
runas /user:"" "" >nul 2>&1 0>con
comp nul nul 0>nul
```

The commands are executed like the enter has been pressed.I would rather expect something like this when input redirection is used but not output.

Comment: how I explain myself this - after output is done the cmd terminates the streams (?) like in &1 , &2  .In case of  `0` there's nothing to output as its for user input and so redirection is done immediately.But cmd treats it like `2` or `1` and terminates it before the input is done.Of course this could be a wrong theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's follow the [MS documentacion](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx).

We have handle duplication

```
2>&1   : Take the handle in the stream 1, 
         duplicate it 
         and place the copy as the handle in stream 2.
```

and redirection operators

```
2>file : Get a handle to the file and 
         place the handle to be used as stream 2

<file  : Get a handle to the file and
         place the handle to be used as stream 1 (implicit)
```

In all cases, a handle is obtained (copied or not) and placed as the handle for the indicated stream.

Now your code

```
set /p= 0>nul
        ^^^^^ .... What does it mean?
```

This means: open a stream to `nul` "device", and set the handle to this stream (copy/duplicate it) as the handle of stream 0

So, these two lines are equivalent (more or less, see the edit)

```
set /p= <nul
set /p= 0>nul
```

In both cases the handle stored in `&0` points to `nul` device.

**edited** to adapt to comments and to complete the answer.

> Not then why `set /p= 0<con` and `set /p= 0>con` give different results?

That is, the first one reads from console and the second one no. If, as previously indicated, in both cases the stream `&0` contains a handle to the same device, what is the reason for this behaviour?

Handle open options. The device being asociated with `&0` is the same, but this is not the case for the handle we get. At least so says the documentation:

- `<` generates a read-only handle
- `>` generates a write only handle

So,

- in the first case it is possible to read from the handle as the console can be readed and the handle allows reading
- in the second case the console can be readed but it is not possible to read from the handle as it is a write handle

Comment: Not then why `set /p= 0<con` and `set /p= 0>con` give different results?

Comment: @npocmaka, answer updated (and slightly reformated).

Comment: Still not convinced that this is the answer.Still think  is possible `>` to has a higher prio and the stream is terminated when the output is done.

Comment: @npocmaka, `set /p=test 0>con 0<con`?